# C# Windows Forms SQL database table Cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, encoding

I created a Windows form application in C# and using a SQL database. I am from Bulgaria and I need cyrillic characters in my database but whet I use cyrillic character they appear in database as '?'.

If anyone can help me I will be very happy because this is my first Windows forms application!

See image -> [See image](http://postimg.org/image/nnkge0iql/)

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 2):

To successfully store (and retrieve) Cyrillic characters, you must

1. use `nvarchar(n)` datatype in your database table - are you?
2. when inserting, either use the `N'` prefix (`INSERT INTO YourTable(...) VALUES(N'....', ...)` or make sure the calling application (your C# code) also uses and specifies `nvarchar` (Unicode characters)